# try command not being recognized in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

No matter where in the code I put this, it chokes.

```
    try {
        $Result = true;
    } 
    catch(exception) {
    }
```

The error occurs as soon as I close the try command '}'.

I checked my php.ini and it is reporting all errors.  Am I missing some sort of setting?

Why isn't my wampserver recognizing this command? Dreamweaver flags the line as an error, and browser testing chokes at the same point.  My wampserver is only 6 months old.  It has to be current.

Any ideas?

Comment: "the error", "it chokes" how about posting the actual error

Comment: As stated by my buddy Dagon, we need to see the actual error message you are getting to be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax is:

```
try
{
    $Result = true;
} 
catch(\Exception $e) {
}
```

`Exception` is just a **[Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)**, that determies what exactly exceptions to catch. You even may to use several catch blocks with a single try block for each per exception type.

```
try
{
    $Result = true;
} 
catch(\Exception $e) {
    // do something
}
catch(\RuntimeException $e) {
    // do something else
}
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: @BLaZuRE maybe you tell me why there is a syntax error? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The error thrown is the undefined keyword `exception`

The code should be rewritten as:

```
try {
    $Result = true;
} catch(Exception $exc){
}
```

Note that `Exception` is only a type hint.